# Existence in real-analysis

Tags: real-analysis

could you help me with the following problem?
I am looking at $\mathbb{R}$ construction in Cauchy sequence analysis.

Suppose the polynomial functions are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Let the polynomial function be such that $f (x) = x^{n}-a$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R^{+}}$. Prove that there exists exactly a positive real number c such that $f (c) = 0$. This number c is called the énesima root of a and is denoted $a^{1/n}$.

I have tried applying the mean value theorem, but I do not think my argument is correct since we have never used it in class

Comment: Consider the set of numbers for which $x^n \leq a$. What do you know about the boundary of this set?

Comment: Use Intermediate Value Theorem instead

Comment: @MorganRodgers, That the supreme of said set is a?

Comment: @AlexG., We have not proved the intermediate value theorem, but I find it interesting. Could you tell me how would you use it?

Comment: $f(0) < 0$, and since $x^n$ is unbounded and increasing (on $x>0$), eventually $f(x) > 0$ for big enough $x$. Then IVT implies $f(x)=0$ somewhere.

Comment: @AlexG. Thank you very much, it is an interesting application, I will ask my teacher if I can use it

Comment: Prove that If $0 < x < y$ then $0 <x^n < y^n$.  Let $A=\{x| x^n < a\}$.  Prove $A$ is not empty. Let $B=\{x|x^n > a\}$.  Prove $B$ is not empty. Use $x<y\implies x^n<y^n$ so $A$ is bounded above by any element in $B$ and $B$ is bounded below by any element in $A$. So $\sup A$ and $\inf B$ exist.  Prove that it is impossible for $\sup A^2 \ne a$ and it is impossible for $\sup B^2 \ne a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ .

$f(x)=x^n-a$; $a\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

**(Existance)**
$f(0)=-a<0$ and by *Archimedean-property*   $\exists M>0 $  such that $\forall x>M$ such that $x^n>a \implies f(x)=x^n-a>0,\forall x>M$ .
Then by IVT we have there exist $c>0$  such that $f(c)=0\implies c^n=a$.

**(Uniqueness)**
Observe that $f$ is differentiable every where on $(0,\infty)$.Also observe that $f'(x)>0$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Suppose we had $c_1,c_2\in \mathbb R$ and $c_1 \not=c_2$ such that $f(c_1)=f(c_2)$ then by Rolle's Theorem $\exists d\in (c_1,c_2)$ such that $f'(d)=0$, but this is not possible.
Hence there exist unique $c>0$ such that $f(c)=0$.

Comment: What I am going to say is not formal hence should not be taken seriously................. **Intermediate Value theorem** is just- If You just try to draw a line starting from a point below X-axis(i.e.region where y co-ordinate is negative) and end at a point above X-axis (i.e.region where y co-ordinate is positive) you have to cross the X-axis. That,s all my friend @Samuel

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome! But an upvote would have sufficed.  :P

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely not suppose to use the Mean Value Theorem/Rolle's Theorem/Intermediate Value Theorem for this. It is highly likely that trying to prove Rolle's Theorem without assuming the property of the real numbers in question would be impossible.

All you need to do is consider $A = \{x : x \in \mathbb{R} \ | x^{n} \leq a\}$.
This set is nonempty and bounded from above, therefore the supremum of $A$ exists, call it $c$. Now you should argue that 1: $c$ is positive, 2: $c^{n} = a$, 3: prove that $c$ is unique with this property.

Comment: But proving that "supremum" is my required $c$ requires some work isn't it ? I mean some manipulation , right?

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: If $x>0, y> 0$ then $x<y \iff x^n < y^n$ for any natural $n$.

Pf: If $x < y$ then $x^1 < y^1$.

If $x^k < y^k$ then $x^{k+1}=x^k*x < y^k*x < y^k*y < y^{k+1}$.

So by induction $x<y\implies x^n < y^n$.

And if $x=y$ then $x^n = y^n$.

And if $x>y$ then $y< x$ and $y^n < x^n$ and $x^n > y^n$.

So $x< y \iff x^n < y^n$.

....

Let $A = \{x| x>0, x^n < a\}$ and $B = \{x|x>0, x^n > a\}$.

Claim: $A$ is not empty.

Pf: If $A$ is empty then $x^n \ge a$ for all $x > 0$.  So $a> 0$ is a lower bound of $\{x^n|x>0\}$.  We also know that $a < 1$ because otherwise for all $q: 0< q < 1$ we'd have $q^n < 1 < a$ and $q \in A$.  So $a^n < a$ and $a \in A$. So we have a contradiction.

Claim: $B$ is not empty.

Pf: If $B$ is empty then $a$ is an upper bound of $\{x^n|x>\}$.  We know $a > 1$ because otherwise for all $q: q>1$ we'd have $q^n>1\ge a$. And so $a^n > a$ and $a \in B$.

Now for $x>0,y>0$ we have $x< y\iff x^n < y^n$ we have any element of $A$ is a lower bound of $B$ and every element of $B$ is an upper bound of $A$ so $\sup A$ and $\inf B$ exist in the reals and $\sup A \le \inf B$.

Now if $\sup A < \inf B$ there are $w,z: 0< \sup A < w<z < \inf B$ but $w,z\not \in A$ and $w,z\not \in B$ and $w,z >0$ so $w^2\ge a;w^2\le a; z^2 \ge a; z^2 \le a$ so $w^2 =z^2 = a$ but $w< y$ so $w^2 < z^2$ and that's a contradiction.

So $\sup A = \inf B$.

Let $\sup A = \inf B = k$.

If $k^n < a$ then

If $k^n < a$ then.... bear with me... this is magic...

Let $0< h < \min(\frac {a-k^n}{n(k+1)^{n-1}}, 1)$.

The $(k+h)^2 - k^2 = [k+h-k][(k+h)^{n-1} + (k+h)^{n-2}k + ... + (k+h)k^{n-2}+k^{n-1}]\le$

$[k+h-k][(k+h)^{n-1} + (k+h)^{n-2}(k+h) + .... + (k+h)(k+h)^{n-2}+(k+h)^{n-1}]=$

$h[(k+h)^{n-1}+(k+h)^{n-1}+(k+h)^{n-1}+....+(k+h)^{n-1}=$

$hn(k+h)^{n-1} <$

$\frac {a-k^n}{n(k+1)^{n-1}}n(k+h)^{n-1}=$

$(a-k^n)\frac {(k+h)^{n-1}}{(k+1)^{n-1}} <$

$a-k^n$.

Therefore $(k+h)^2 < a$ and $k+h \in A$ but $k=\sup A$ so that's impossible.

So $k^n \ge a$.

If $a  < k^n$ we can do the same thing with $k = \inf B$.

Let $0 < h < {k^n- a}{nk^{n-1}}$

$k^n - (k-h)^n \le hnk^{n-1}< k^n - a$

$a < (k-h)^n$ so $k-h \in B$ which contradicts $k=\inf B$.

So $k^n = a$.

And by the Lemma at the very beginning, $k$ is unique.